# How to run smart contracts in the Cardano Blockchain?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, cardano-cli, cardano-node, plutus-pab

I know that since Alonzo was launched smart contracts can be published in the blockchain now, but I have no idea how to do it.

I have read some articles about the Plutus Application Backend though, it's a platform to work with Plutus scripts and provides an API to run those scripts via an endpoint that it's embedded in the script. But this means that smart contracts that run in Plutus are still off-chain in the local machine instead of being running on-chain. Is this true?

Or am I missing something like other library that works with the Plutus smart contracts and can interact with my web DApps?. Please if there is any suggestion I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> How to run smart contract in Cardano Blockchain?

PAB isn't available yet outside of development. The only way to submit and interact with smart contracts on-chain is with the cardano-cli. [Here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/Alonzo-testnet/blob/main/Alonzo-tutorials/Plutus_transactions_tutorial.md) is a thorough tutorial on how to do that.

> But it means that smartcontract that run in plutus still off-chain or running in local machine instead of running on blockchain. Is that true?

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but if you are curious where the smartcontracts live, my answer over [here](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/2351/1130) might help.

Comment: honestly, i would like to create a program for my thesis for achieving my bachelor. so mostly my dapps would be running in public testnet with PAB. is it possible?

Comment: I don’t understand, even Charles Hoskinson said the PAB is released. The GitHub page list a pre-release of the PAB. I thought it would be possible (even if at own risks) to connect to the mainnet with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can run smart contracts with the [cardano-serilization-lib](https://github.com/emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib) and its js libraries. Check https://github.com/Berry-Pool/spacebudz to see an example. This allows you to host a web dApp where the user can connect with their Nami wallet, sign transactions that can contain datum, redeemer, everything needed to interact with smart contracts.